# MATLAB - Split a large matrix into submatrices efficiently

Tags: performance, matlab, calculation

I have a large rectangular matrix (like 3000x3000) in `MATLAB` and I need to split it into several square submatrices (starting from 1x1 and ending at 3000x3000) to do some scientific calculations.
a simplified example would be as follows:

01 02 03 04

05 06 07 08

09 10 11 12

13 14 15 16

submatrices:

1x1: [01],[02].... [16]

2x2: [[01,02], [05,06]], [[02,03], [06,07]].... [[11,12],[15,16]]

until

4x4: same as the given matrix.

I have used several for loops but it takes a lot of time and seems not efficient.
How can I do that more efficiently?

Comment: Have you tried `reshape` for each of the submatrix sizes?

Comment: Of course that assumes that the matrix dimensions are evenly divisible by the submatrix dimensions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, dear @beaker. Would you mind giving me some sample code for this problem using `reshape`?  I haven't used it yet.

Comment: Also, what sort of calculations are you doing on these submatrices? Do you have the image processing toolbox? The fastest way to do this is not to create the submatrices at all, but to perform the calculations on a limited area of the original matrix.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to use it right now and inform you.

Comment: Yes, it's related to the images. I haven't used any toolboxes yet, but if they are helpful for this problem, I will use them.

Comment: Sorry, the code I gave you is not going to work for all of the submatrix sizes, but if you have a look at the documentation for `resize`, you should be able to get it to work.

Comment: **cellfun()** on top of **mat2cell()** will be easier on the eyes. Performance wise you could tinker with **parfeval()** with these repeats, the optimal arrangement depends on the actual data and calculations.

Comment: Could you please write a simple code here? I'm a bit confused about the solution